# How to use an integer array as index of a char array in C?

Tags: c

So I'm trying to store positions that I get from a calculation to an integer array and then use these positions (elements of the integer array) as the positions of the char array for a certain comparison.

Here is the sample code:

```
int arrayposition[10];
char arrayword[10];
char string[10];
...
.
.
// I want to do a strcmp to compare string and arrayword
//suppose
for (int i = 0;;) {
    if (strcmp(arrayword[i], string[arrayposition])) {     //Obviously this is not possible( array within an 
                                                     // array)
       //do something
    }
}
```

What is the best way to use `arrayposition` as the index for string.
Eg: `arrayposition[2] = {1,3,5};`

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer:

```
const char *arrayword[10] = { "word1", "word2", ... };

    if(strncmp(arrayword[i], string + arrayposition, strlen[arrayword + i]))
```

This compares the entire string in in arrayword + i with the string starting at arrayposition.

Comment: string is char* type and arrayposition is int* type. How can we do a binary operation on these two?

Comment: @technextgen: Either arrayposition should be an int type or there's a missing loop and it should be `arryposition[j]`.